# Prove $m=2^n + 1$ then $n$ must be of the form $2^i$ if $m$ is a prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I need to find the proof of expression given in the title. There are primes of the form $2^2 + 1$, $2^4 + 1$ and so on. So I'm thinking if $m$ is the prime then it must be of the form $m=2^{2^i} + 1$. I probably need more details for the proof.

Comment: There's a proof given here :) 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#Other_theorems_about_Fermat_numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this one, simpler case first.

Assume $n=pq$, p, q odd primes, $p>2$, $q>2$.

In this case $m=2^{pq}+1=(2+1)(2^{pq-1}-2^{pq-2}+2^{pq-3}-...)$.

Therefore $3 \vert m$ and m is not a prime.

More general case.

Assume $n=pj$, p odd prime, $p>2$, j any integer.

So $m=2^{pj}+1=(2^{j}+1)((2^{j})^{p-1}-(2^{j})^{p-2}+(2^{j})^{p-3}-...)$.

From here $2^{j}+1 \vert m$ and m is not a prime.

Therefore if m is a prime n must be of the form $2^i$.

Comment: Sorry, but your calculation is still not correct.
Take $p=3$, $j=2$ for example. Then the left hand side of your equation is
$$2^{pj}-(-1)=2^6+1=65$$ whereas the right hand side is
$$(2^j-(-1))((2^j)^{p-1}+(2^j)^{p-2}+\ldots)=(2^2-(-1))((2^2)^2+(2^2)^1+(2^2)^0)=(4+1)(4^2+4+1)=(4+1)(16+4+1)=5\cdot 21=105$$

Comment: @jpvee: i got it. posted an update.

Answer (score 2):

If $u$ is an odd divisor of $n$, then $n=u\cdot k$ for some integer $k$, and

$$m=2^n+1=(2^k)^u+1=\left((2^k)^{u-1}-(2^k)^{u-2}\pm\ldots+1\right)\cdot(2^k+1),$$

so $m$ cannot be prime if $u>1$.

Comment: found a bit simpler proof. assume $p \div n$, $p > 2$ and p is a prime. therefore $n=pj$, $m=2^{pj}+1=2^{pj}-(-1)$. from here $m=(2-(-1))(2^{pj-1}+2^{pj-2}+2^{pj-3}+...)$ and $3 \div m$. therefore n must be of the form $2^i$.

Comment: @php--: Look at the case $n=6$; there, $m=65$ which is **not** divisible by $3$. (To find the flaw in your calculation and to fix it for odd $n$ is left as an exercise...)

Comment: this proof assumed that n is not divisible by 2

Comment: did some search. check the reply that i posted.